# How to trim decimal from double value in c#

Tags: c#, double, rounding

I am trying to remove last digit from **1719.4703776041661** double value in c#. I would like to have only 12 digits in double value. How can i achieve this?

Tried following, but still getting same value as input (13 digits).

```
Math.Round(1719.4703776041661, 12) // Same Result with 13 digits
double.parse(value.ToString("N12"))
```

Comment: This might be an X/Y problem. There are lots of values doubles cant represent in base 2, they are just not capable of it

Comment: `Math.Round(1719.4703776041661, 12)` works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/wWECSj

Comment: one heck can work, change to string and then trim last characters and again convert to double

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Can you try with .Net 4.7.2 compiler? https://dotnetfiddle.net/IVKKy6

Comment: @viveknuna Tried this also double.parse(value.ToString("N12")) but no help

Comment: @VenkyDhana its worse than you think https://dotnetfiddle.net/DH4pnH, please read my first comment

Comment: @VenkyDhana i am saying this `double x = Convert.ToDouble( d.ToString().Substring(0, d.ToString().Length - 1));`

Comment: Not all seemingly innocent numbers __can__ actually be stored in a float or double. So this may well be __impossible__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a precision problem. Check this:

```
double d = 1719.4703776041849;
```

Place a breakpoint and check the value stored in `d`, you will be surprised it doesn't match. That's because the number requires higher precision than what `double` offers.

If you need such precision then you must use `decimal` instead of `double`. This will work:

```
decimal d = 1719.4703776041661M; //Need the M suffix to denote a decimal value.
var z = Math.Round(d, 12); //It returns 1719.470377604166
```

Comment: Actually it is not so much about precision as such but about 'decimal precision'. Decimal type will resolve it. But other numbers like 1/3 will still be impossible to store.